# C++ allocator allocate/deallocate

Tags: memory, allocator

The following code works peacefully without segfault and memory leak.

```
::std::allocator<int> alloc;

auto ptr = alloc.allocate(1);
alloc.deallocate(ptr, 1);
```

Without calling deallocate, memory leak is expected (4 bytes lost definitely).

```
::std::allocator<int> alloc;
auto ptr = alloc.allocate(1);
```

However, the following code doesn't introduce leak. Why the memory is still being freed even though I call deallocate with `n=0`?

```
::std::allocator<int> alloc;
auto ptr = alloc.allocate(1);
alloc.deallocate(ptr, 0);
```

Also I expect the following code to throw a segfault, but it didn't. What could be the reason?

```
::std::allocator<int> alloc;
auto ptr = alloc.allocate(1);
alloc.deallocate(ptr, 1000);
```

All are compiled without optimization. Memory detection is based on valgrind.

Comment: The argument for the size has to be right, otherwise *the behavior is undefined*. Well, the fact that it works is unexpected indeed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably because the compiler has optimized that out as you do nothing to the allocated memory.
2. Probably because the C API [std::free](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free) in `cstdlib` doesn't require size at all.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ specification (ISO/IEC 14882:2014) defines in Table 28 for deallocate(p,n):

> All n T objects in the area pointed to by p shall be destroyed prior to this call. 
>   n shall match the value passed to allocate to obtain this memory. Does not throw
>   exceptions. (...)

So you are right that the correct size should be provided as n. (If not you are in "undefined behavior" land.) 
The std::allocator's deallocate implementation you are currently using might ignore the size. (Like e. g. MSVC's version, as this stack overflow question here indicates.) However the deallocate implementation or the debug version of another allocate might behave differently. So use the matching value.